# Is ArrayPool<T>.Rent(Int32) Method thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, thread-safety

I just found out about ArrayPool existence, but it's documentation is somewhat lacking.

I'd like to know if [Rent(.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.rent?view=netcore-2.1) and [Return(.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.return?view=netcore-2.1) are thread-safe.

Edit: looks like I didn't notice the "Thread Safety" part of documentation; but reading some of the comments and answers I was relieved I wasn't the only one that didn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update Comment from [ta.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is)**

> It literally says on
>   [Thread safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netcore-2.1#thread-safety) This
>   class is thread-safe. All members may be used by multiple threads
>   concurrently

**Original**

It doesn't say it on learn.microsoft.com, however there is a few references to the fact it is

[Add a new System.Buffers namespace to the BCL for Resource Pooling](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4547)

> **The Pool will be lightweight and thread-safe**, allowing for fast Rent
>   and Return calls from any thread within the process, along with
>   minimal locking overhead, and 0 heap allocations on most Rent calls
>   (exceptions to this will be called out below in the description of the
>   Rent function).

[Pooling large arrays with ArrayPool](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/)

> Recommended: use the ArrayPool.Shared property, which returns a
>   shared pool instance. **It’s thread safe** and all you need to remember is
>   that it has a default max array length, equal to 2^20 (1024*1024 = 1
>   048 576).

.

Comment: *It doesn't say it on learn.microsoft.com* It literally says on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1 *This class is thread-safe. All members may be used by multiple threads concurrently.*

Comment: @ta.speot.is ahh so it does

Answer (score 4):

> it's documentation is somewhat lacking.

[You can read about thread safety under *Thread Safety*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1):

> ## Thread Safety
>
> This class is thread-safe. All members may be used by multiple threads concurrently.